# jquery if have html tag

Tags: jquery

I have some code, the `p.words` is hidden, I tried to make a judge, if next `div` has `span` tag, then show the `p.words`, else keep the css rule.

I use `jquery.next` and `jquery.find` to make a judge `$(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')`, but it will show all the `p.words` even the next `div` has no `span` tag

```
<style>
.words{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.words').each(function(){
        if($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')){
            $(this).css('display','block');
        }           
    });
});
</script>
<a>Voodoo
   <p class="words"> 1</p><!-- do not show -->
</a>
<div class="col">
   <ul>
      <li>ATI Rage128 Pro</li><!-- no span tag -->
   </ul>
</div>
<a>NVIDIA
   <p class="words"> GeForce2 MX</p><!-- show --> 
</a>
<div class="col">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <span>NVIDIA GeForce2 MX 400</span><!-- have span tag -->
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>ATI 9200SE</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 if($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')){
```

to

```
 if($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span').length > 0){
```

The result of `$(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')` is an array which may or may not be empty, but will always resolve to `true` in your condition.

Comment: AlienWebguy has it right; I would also simplify your code to use the next-siblings-selector but this is the core of your problem.

Comment: The spans wouldn't necessarily be siblings - he just wanted to know if the parent's next sibling contains any child `span` nodes. His selector sequence is spot on.

Comment: One small note: rather than the above selector returning an array, it returns a jQuery object which also has a `.length` property: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: `console.log($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')) // []`

Comment: `console.log($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span'));` outputs `jQuery()` for me.

Comment: Interesting. FF? Chrome outputs `[]`

Comment: Firefox, Safari, Opera & IE all output objects and Chrome outputs an array when using `console.log()` however I noticed if you use `alert()` then Chrome alerts `[object object]` like the other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can vastly simplify your code with this:

http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Also, I think the source of your problem is that find returns an empty array which does not evaluate to "false". Try this code:

```
if ($.find("doesnotexist")){console.log("Hi")}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit:

```
if($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span')){
```

If there are no `<span>` tags found this will not return false (it will return an empty jQuery object). Try adding `.length` to the end of your selector; which will return 0 if the jQuery object is empty (0 is truthily equal to false):

```
if($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span').length){
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above change to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/qfqJZ/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a slight change to your if statement:

```
if ($(this).parent().next('.col').find('span').length > 0) {
   ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JMdC6/